# Send request to server iOS

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to figure out how to send data to the server but currently without any progress.

What I know

On the server I have got some php script that return me data in response

for example with this URL: `http://test.com/mobile_api/register`

this script get next parameters:

```
id
name
info
time
```

so the string which I need looking like below

http://test.com/mobile_api/register?id=1000&name=alex&info=1.0&time=10000

What is best way to send this is string on the server

Now I'm trying to use `ASIHTTPRequest`. Can anybody send an example how to create correct request with my parameters.

Comment: On a side note, if you're doing a RESTful API, you shouldn't do a GET to create/write server side.  It should be a post, ideally with the data in the body.

Comment: It's a pity that 'let me google that for you' links are forbidden in comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code should help you

```
-(void)sendRequest
{
    int userId=10, time=10000;
    NSString *name = @"ABC";
    float info = 1.0;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/mobile_api/register?id=%d&name=%@&info=%f&time=%d",userId,name,info,time];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    //You need to add ASIHTTPRequestDelegate in header(.h) file
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    // Use when fetching binary data
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
}
```